# It is permitted vs It is allowed

Tags: word-usage

> A)It is not permitted to smoke in the kitchen.
>
> B)It is not allowed to smoke in the kitchen.

According to Practical English Usage(42) the passive structure with **it**,is only possible with permit.
To me sentence B seems to be correct and I can't understand why it is wrong to use it.

And according to Cambridge dictionary example:

> The loophole has allowed hundreds of drink-drivers to avoid prosecution.

Unlike the previous accepted answer for this question  I think Something can allow something else to happen as well as something can be permitted.

Comment: Neither are particularly idiomatic to my ear. Normally we'd make the forbidden activity the subject: ***Smoking in the kitchen** is not permitted/allowed* (there's no significant difference between the choices for the final word).

Comment: If we said, "Smoking is not ____ in the kitchen," then either word could be used. But I agree with @Fumble, neither of your examples sound quite right. Does PEU(42) have other examples?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes I've read the answers to that question but I'm not still convinced.What I mean is the answer with is accepted as the correct one says that A thing or action can be permitted but considering the example in collins dictionary The loophole has allowed hundreds of drink-drivers to avoid prosecution.something is allowing some thing else to happens isn't it?!

Comment: @J.R. No unfortunately it's the only example

Comment: Per [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/19319/126) to the original question, constructions such as ***It is allowed to use the boat*** don't usually sound good to native speakers. That's to say *neither* of your examples are idiomatically natural, so both you and the OP of the original are really wasting your time trying to find out which one is "better". The construction seems to me to work a bit better with *It is **forbidden** to smoke here,* but I still don't like it. Stick to ***Smoking is forbidden here*** - or ***You are** forbidden to smoke here.*

Comment: Important point: the sentence from Cambridge is not a passive-it construction, so the guidance in PEU doesn't apply.